# Google App Engine take long time to process Request for the first time after Redeployment?

Tags: google-app-engine, startup

In my Google app engine project every time i redeploy the project and make request for the first time it take around 1.5 sec to perform the operation. but in next request it takes only 0.196 sec time.

As Example:
When i query on data-store to retrieve list of data Time-stamp are:

> ```
> 1st Request(Around 1.5 sec)             2nd Request(Around 0.196 sec)
> Start Time  1399448227701               Start Time  1399448369720
> End Time    1399448229292               End Time    1399448369916
> ```

So my question is why app engine take too much time to respond for the first time after Redeployment??

Thanks In Advance.!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it can depend on several things, but most likely it corresponds with the time needed for your instance to start, it's called a loading request. Once the instance is started, the next requests are much more faster.

You observe this after redeployment, but you can also see the same behaviour if your App Engine instance is idle for a too long time (no requests received), then it shuts down and the next request coming will have to wait for a new instance to start.

You can change the idle time setting along with some other stuff like number of instances always on (resident instances) etc.. Fine tuning these is your best option.

Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances?hl=fr) here it explains a lot about this.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. i have another doubt how to change the idle time setting for app engine instance?

Comment: After any update, the instances will be restarted. You should test the instance as a different version, so you know it has started and then promote it to default if you wish to avoid that startup cost.

Comment: In the App Engine administration console, under Application Settings you could change the idle instances settings to have at least 1 instance running all the time (by default it's Automatic), so you would always have one instance ready to handle requests right away. Or you can use the module configuration, directly in your app.yaml file (or equivalent for other languages than Python) and set the idle_timeout parameter to a higher value. Check this documentation for more details: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

Comment: Can one use cronjobs to keep an instance active and prevent it being idle for the maximum time limit set? Please advise.Thanks!

Comment: You can do that, but what is simpler event is to change your app settings to have 1 instance always active.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue hosting my backend application with Google. I found my instance was going to sleep every 15 minutes if there was no activity.

The solution for me was to set up a cloud scheduler task to do a small GET request to my application every 14 minutes, within a certain time frame e.g. 6pm - 10pm.

Very easy to set up, but it will generate more cost due to more resources being used so if you do go with this option, be sure to adjust the timing for it to lower the cost.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The Google Cloud guy [answered well this question here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/app-engine-resident-instances-and-the-startup-time-problem-8c6587040a80).

TL;DR :

**If you have a high-frequency, lots-of-instance-churn scenario, and a slow cold-boot time**, then resident instances are the best bet. Yes, you end up with more total instances, but letting GAE handle the scaling up-and-down of resident instances will respond more gracefully to shifts in traffic load that you have over time.

**If you handle low-frequency traffic, with occasional bursts, and a slow cold-boot time**, then keeping an always-cron instance around is ideal since you can handle the initial traffic load gracefully, with a lower number of total instances.

In my case, I added the following to my `app.yaml` file, and it did the job as expected :

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
```

I will monitor the bill though. If the next bill looks crazy, I will apply an always CRON job instead.